EMR Serverless Writing .orc (or shuffling) to S3 Slow
EMR (serverless) + Spark newbie here.
Currently running a pyspark script on EMR serverless to partition data (in .orc format) from the timestamp column and store it in the s3-output-path bucket in year=yyyy/month=MM/day=dd/hour=hh/minute=mm/<orc-file> directory.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("partition test") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name", "partitioned") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
    .orc(<s3-bucket>)

df = df.withColumn("ts", from_unixtime(col("timestamp") / 1000, "yyyyMMddHHmm"))

df = df.withColumn("year", substring(col("ts"), 1, 4)) \
       .withColumn("month", substring(col("ts"), 5, 2)) \
       .withColumn("day", substring(col("ts"), 7, 2)) \
       .withColumn("hour", substring(col("ts"), 9, 2)) \
       .withColumn("minute", substring(col("ts"), 11, 2))

df = df.drop("ts")

df = df.repartition(partitions, "year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute")

df.write \
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute") \
    .mode("append") \
    .orc(<s3-output-path>)

spark.stop()

Currently takes 1.5 hrs to run through 150 gb of data (~75,000 files). Any suggestions on improving this? From the logs, it seems like the writing is taking a long time. For example, here are the last few lines of one of the logs that took the longest:
24/08/01 09:34:24 INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 38 spilling sort data of 15.3 GiB to disk (10  times so far)
24/08/01 09:34:44 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /[2600:1f18:8bf:7703:1275:5ac0:48e2:2d45]:42867 after 4 ms (2 ms spent in bootstraps)
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO PhysicalFsWriter: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=08/hour=11/minute=35/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 blockSize: 268435456 compression: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO WriterImpl: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=08/hour=11/minute=35/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 options: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO PhysicalFsWriter: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=14/hour=03/minute=42/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 blockSize: 268435456 compression: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO WriterImpl: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=14/hour=03/minute=42/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 options: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO PhysicalFsWriter: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=14/hour=21/minute=43/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 blockSize: 268435456 compression: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO WriterImpl: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=14/hour=21/minute=43/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 options: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO PhysicalFsWriter: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=15/hour=00/minute=28/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 blockSize: 268435456 compression: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 09:34:48 INFO WriterImpl: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=15/hour=00/minute=28/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 options: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 10:02:16 INFO PhysicalFsWriter: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=15/hour=00/minute=31/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 blockSize: 268435456 compression: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 10:02:16 INFO WriterImpl: ORC writer created for path: s3a://partition-data-test/emr-medium-strength/550exec-30execmem-200strg-hour/year=2024/month=04/day=15/hour=00/minute=31/part-00747-8552780c-ee26-4f71-b955-f9edf3bab803.c000.snappy.orc with stripeSize: 67108864 options: Compress: SNAPPY buffer: 131072
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO StagingCommitter: Starting: Task committer attempt_202408010928329097189196486532857_0003_m_000747_4634: needsTaskCommit() Task attempt_202408010928329097189196486532857_0003_m_000747_4634
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO StagingCommitter: Task committer attempt_202408010928329097189196486532857_0003_m_000747_4634: needsTaskCommit() Task attempt_202408010928329097189196486532857_0003_m_000747_4634: duration 0:00.001s
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: No need to commit output of task because needsTaskCommit=false: attempt_202408010928329097189196486532857_0003_m_000747_4634
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO Executor: Finished task 747.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4634). 7545 bytes result sent to driver
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver from 2600:1f18:8bf:7703:ef9a:8d63:d02e:92e2:39655 disconnected during shutdown
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver from [2600:1f18:8bf:7703:ef9a:8d63:d02e:92e2]:39655 disconnected during shutdown
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
24/08/01 10:29:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/08/01 10:29:07 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
24/08/01 10:29:07 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
24/08/01 10:29:07 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.

Current specs for pre-initialised workers:
1x Spark drivers (4 vCPU, 16 GB memory, shuffle-enabled, 20 GB disk)
500x Spark executors (4 vCPU, 16 GB memory, shuffle-enabled, 50 GB disk)
spark.executor.cores = 4
spark.executor.instances = 3
spark.executor.memory = 14G
spark.driver.cores = 4
spark.driver.memory = 14G

Thanks in advance!
Tried modifying the spark.executor.cores, .instances, .memory with not much different in the time. Tried increasing the memory and executor count (in the pre-initialised worker setting).
